# Systemd Service stops when closing the last SFTP / SSH Session

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, services, systemd, teamspeak

I recently moved my Server from a virtual machine to a new machine.

Since then I sometimes have the inexplicable event, that my Teamspeak Server stops (and that auto-restarts because that's how I configured it) when closing the last open session from sftp / ssh that was logged in as the user that the service runs on.

So basically my linux sends a kill signal to my TS3 server when closing the last open ssh connection. Here the journalctl log when crashing:

```
Jun 30 10:48:03 ubuntu-server ts3server_startscript.sh[7505]: Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server
Jun 30 10:51:30 ubuntu-server systemd[1]: teamspeak.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
Jun 30 10:51:30 ubuntu-server systemd[1]: teamspeak.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 30 10:51:30 ubuntu-server systemd[1]: teamspeak.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 30 10:51:33 ubuntu-server systemd[1]: teamspeak.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
```

I use the following SystemD Config:

```
[Unit]
Description=TeamSpeak 3 Server
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/teamspeak/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/
User=teamspeak
Group=teamspeak
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/teamspeak/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh start inifile=ts3server.ini
ExecStop=/home/teamspeak/teamspeak3-server_inux_amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh stop
PIDFile=/home/teamspeak/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/ts3server.pid
RestartSec=3
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any ideas? I cannot explain it..

Answer (score 2):

Likely to do with lingering as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User).

Solution:

`sudo loginctl enable-linger <username>`